# Run Revit 2016 with selected affinity vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, affinity

I've been trying to run Revit 2016 with the selected process affinity of my choice:

[image: Affinity]

Below is my current code that is suppose to run it on CPU 0 (or maybe CPU 1):

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2016\Revit.exe"
myProcess.Start()
Dim thread As ProcessThread = Process.GetProcessById(myProcess.Id).Threads(0)
thread.IdealProcessor = 1
thread.ProcessorAffinity = CType(1, IntPtr)
Dim instance As Process = Process.GetProcessById(myProcess.Id)
instance.ProcessorAffinity = New IntPtr(1)
instance.ProcessorAffinity = CType(1, IntPtr)
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this code does not work every time, it only works every few launches, and all other times, after going to task manager, I still find that Revit is running on all processors :(

It will be appreciated if someone can give me a hint as to what I'm missing.

Many thanks,

Comment: You have not described what you are attempting to accomplish.  If its not doing what is expected, then a description of the current behavior along with a description of the expected behavior is needed in order to help you.